# Axios callback function not working in put method

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, response

I am trying to update MySQL database with Axios. My problem is data updated successfully but the axios callback not working. whereas post, delete and get callback working perfecly. Here is my code given below:

Frontend code:

```
 UpdateTeacher = (id) =>{
      const editedata = {
        id: id,
        fname: this.state.fname,
        lname: this.state.lname,
        roles: this.state.roles,
        join_date: this.state.join_date,
        email: this.state.email,
        assign_subject: this.state.assign_subject
      };
    
     axios.put(`http://localhost:3001/edit/${id}`, editedata)
      .then((res) => {
        // I cant get any console.log neither any state set here
        this.setState({
          success: "Update data Successfully!", 
          type:"success",
          isEdit:false
        });
       
        console.log(res.data.json);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({ 
            error: "Error! Please try again later!", 
            type:"error"
        });
      })
  }
```

Backend code:

```
app.put("/edit/:id", (req, res) => {

    const {id }       = req.params.id;
    const fname     = req.body.fname;
    const lname     = req.body.lname;
    const roles     = req.body.roles;
    const joining   = req.body.join_date;
    const email     = req.body.email;
    const assign_subject  = req.body.assign_subject;
    
   var updateData = req.body;
   console.log(updateData);
 
db.query(`UPDATE teacher SET fname=?, lname=?, roles=?, join_date=?, email=?, assign_subject=? WHERE id=?`,[fname, lname, roles,joining,email,assign_subject, req.params.id]),(err,result)=>{

    if (err) return console.error(err.message);
    res.status(200).send(results);
    console.log("Updated Row(s):", results.affectedRows);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few issues here that could cause problems. In your server code, you have to return a response in event of an error or the server will hang.

Something like this:

```js
if (err) return res.status(500).send(err.message);
```

Also, you are sending `results`, but the variable you declare in the `db.query` callback is `result`. So the code should be

```js
res.status(200).send(result);
console.log("Updated Row(s):", result.affectedRows);
```

Thirdly, in your client code you are logging with `console.log(res.data.json)`, but I think that should be just `console.log(res.data)`;

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. As your answer, I changed the variable but no luck still status is first 'Pending' then failed after sometimes. here is the new code.
 
 `db.query(`UPDATE teacher SET fname=?, lname=?, roles=?, join_date=?, email=?, assign_subject=? WHERE id=?`,
[fname, lname, roles,joining,email,assign_subject, req.params.id]),(err,result)=>{
    
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err.message);
    res.status(200).send(result);
    console.log("Updated Row(s):", result.affectedRows);
}
});`

Comment: @B.M.RafiulAlam I added another issue I saw to my answer. See if that helps. If not, can you show the output of your server logs? Also try putting a console log with a simple string like '--------' before your client side logs. If the value passed to console.log() is undefined or null, you usually won't see anything show up at all.

Comment: finally I found the main problem was in the MySQL query. I am not sure exactly where! My new working code is in server-side:

 `db.query('UPDATE `teacher` SET ? WHERE id=?',  [req.body, req.params.id], function(err, result) {
    if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.send(result);
        };

    });
})`